# Derivation of Polyanin's formula for Abel's ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-dynamics

There is a general solution from the Polyanin textbook for the equation,

$y\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}-y=Ax+B$

The solution in parametric form is

$x = C \cdot e^{-\int \frac {t \cdot dt}{t^2-t-A}} $ and     $y = C \cdot t \cdot e^{-\int \frac {t \cdot dt}{t^2-t-A}} $

I tried to derive the solution without success. How it was derived?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation can be written as 
$$ \dfrac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y + A x + B}{y}$$
A linear change of independent variable $X = A x + B$ makes this into a homogeneous equation
$$ \dfrac{dy}{dX} = \frac{y+X}{Ay} $$
Now if $y = X t$, this becomes
$$ \dfrac{dt}{dX} = \frac{1 + t - A t^2}{A X t}$$
Now consider $X$ as the independent variable and $t$ as dependent:
$$ \dfrac{dX}{dt} = \frac{AX t}{1 + t - A t^2} $$
This is a homogeneous linear differential equation.  Use the standard formula.